# Sokal's short proof of the uniform boundedness principle

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces

The proof I'm referring to can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1585v2).<sup>1</sup>

I have worked through this proof and am literally at the last line of the UBP proof but am stuck. I have two questions:

Firstly, how does he obtain the inequality $\| x - x_n \| \leq \frac{1}{2}3^{-n}$? I can get $\| x - x_n \| \leq (6)3^{-n}$ via geometric series (unless I've done the arithmetic wrong!). I suspect this will do, based on what follows, but I'd still like to know how to get this estimate.

Secondly, immediately after this, he has an inequality $\| T_n x \| \geq \frac{1}{6} 3^{-n} \| T_n \|$. Where does this inequality come from? Seems like I'm missing something simple here again.

In any case, thanks in advance!

<sup>1</sup>*Sokal, Alan D.*, [**A really simple elementary proof of the uniform boundedness theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.05.450), Am. Math. Mon. 118, No. 5, 450-452 (2011). [ZBL1223.46022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1223.46022), [MR2805031](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2805031).

Comment: I suppose that most proofs can be very short if you skip half the steps!

Comment: @Michael: Ha, so true! In fairness, the author never actually calls it "short"; just "really simple." Can't disagree with that (even if I'm having a little trouble with it...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start with $x_0$. The lemma tells you that for $r=1/3$, the supremum of $\|T_1x'\|$ over
$x'\in B(0,1/3)$ is at least $\|T_1\|/3$. So you can surely find some $x_1\in B(0,1/3)$ such that $\|T_1x_1\|>{2\over 3}\|T_1\|/3$.
(The term ${2\over 3}$ here is just a number less than $1$ but close to it). Now move on. The supremum of $\|T_2x'\|$ over
$x'\in B(x_1,1/9)$ is at least $\|T_2\|/9$. So you can find some $x_2\in B(x_1,1/9)$ such that $\|T_2x_2\|>{2\over 3}\|T_2\|/9$.
And so on.

Next, if you agree with $\|x_n-x\|<{1\over 2}3^{-n}$, then you have:

\begin{align}\left|\, \|T_nx\|-\|T_nx_n\|\,\right|&\leq \|T_nx-T_nx_n\|\leq\|T_n\|\cdot \|x_n-x\|\\ &< \|T_n\|{1\over 2}3^{-n}\end{align}
so
$$-\|T_n\|{1\over 2}3^{-n}+\|T_nx_n\| < \|T_nx\|$$
but $\|T_nx_n\|\geq {2\over 3}3^{-n}\|T_n\|$, so
$$\|T_n\|{1\over 6}3^{-n}=\|T_n\|({2\over 3}-{1\over 2})3^{-n}<\|T_nx\|$$

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful. This answered my second question exactly! And I did convince myself that $|| x_n - x || \leq \frac{1}{2}3^{-n}$; double-checked my work and found an error, so my first question is answered. Thanks again!